# How can I create these buttons with CSS?

Tags: css

How can I create these buttons with CSS?

[image]

Comment: what have you tried so far? those buttons have nothing special, border-radius, some inset box-shadow and a border

Comment: Try [css3button](http://css3button.net/).

Comment: @koala_dev, I've created, but it can not be.

Comment: @koala_dev, Easy to say, if you have the Show?

Comment: http://dabblet.com/gist/5996168

Answer (score 0, accepted):

My attempt:

```
.myButton{
    font-family: Arial, Helvetica, sans-serif;
    font-size: 16px;
    color: #ffffff;
    padding: 14px 40px;
    background: -moz-linear-gradient(
        top,#6CA44B 0%,#4D872B);
    background: -webkit-gradient(
        linear, left top, left bottom, 
        from(#6CA44B),
        to(#4D872B));
    -moz-border-radius: 25px;
    -webkit-border-radius: 25px;
    border-radius: 25px;
    border: 1px solid;
    border-top-color:#7B8E70;
    border-right-color: #536B44;
    border-left-color: #536B44;
    border-bottom-color: #4B643D;
    box-shadow: 0 0 0 5px #e5e5e5,inset 0 1px rgba(255,255,255,0.3);
    text-shadow: 0 1px rgba(0,0,0,0.5);
}

.myButton:hover{
    background: #40781F;
    box-shadow: 0 0 0 5px #e5e5e5,inset 0 2px rgba(0,0,0,0.3);
    color: rgba(255,255,255,0.9);
}
```

**[Demo here](http://jsfiddle.net/yqczv/1/)**

Comment: What is the code for "stupid browse" IE8

Answer (score 1):

You need to add gradient and border raduius

DEMO http://jsfiddle.net/kevinPHPkevin/SXxz7/1/

```
.button {
    -moz-box-shadow:inset 0px 1px 0px 0px #7af013;
    -webkit-box-shadow:inset 0px 1px 0px 0px #7af013;
    box-shadow:inset 0px 1px 0px 0px #7af013;
    background:-webkit-gradient( linear, left top, left bottom, color-stop(0.05, #77d42a), color-stop(1, #5cb811) );
    background:-moz-linear-gradient( center top, #77d42a 5%, #5cb811 100% );
    filter:progid:DXImageTransform.Microsoft.gradient(startColorstr='#77d42a', endColorstr='#5cb811');
    background-color:#77d42a;
    -moz-border-radius:20px;
    -webkit-border-radius:20px;
    border-radius:20px;
    border:3px solid #268a16;
    display:inline-block;
    color:#ffffff;
    font-family:arial;
    font-size:15px;
    font-weight:bold;
    padding:13px 22px;
    text-decoration:none;
}.classname:hover {
    background:-webkit-gradient( linear, left top, left bottom, color-stop(0.05, #5cb811), color-stop(1, #77d42a) );
    background:-moz-linear-gradient( center top, #5cb811 5%, #77d42a 100% );
    filter:progid:DXImageTransform.Microsoft.gradient(startColorstr='#5cb811', endColorstr='#77d42a');
    background-color:#5cb811;
}.classname:active {
    position:relative;
    top:1px;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

you would have to apply a `radius:Xpx` propertie to the item you want to make a button along with `background-color`, `border:3px solid (color here)`.

Comment: You probably mean `border-radius` rather than just plain `radius`.

Comment: My bad that is what i meant.

Comment: Feel free to edit your post then.

Answer (score 0):

Html

```
<button type="button" class="cssButton">Salma</button>
```

Css:

```
cssButton {
    font-family: Arial, Helvetica, sans-serif;
    font-size: 14px;
    color: #ffffff;
    padding: 10px 20px;
    background: -moz-linear-gradient(
        top,
        #dbffe0 0%,
        #2e9e44);
    background: -webkit-gradient(
        linear, left top, left bottom, 
        from(#dbffe0),
        to(#2e9e44));
    -moz-border-radius: 20px;
    -webkit-border-radius: 20px;
    border-radius: 20px;
    border: 2px solid #adadad;
}
```